# How to sort by text first and then text containing numbers

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, sorting

In Sqllite table, I have a column values in a table like

- Mario
- Fly machine
- Evil Dead
- 4 cross Sudoku
- 20 cross Sudoku
- 15 cross Sudoku
- SimCity

how do i sort to have text first, and then sorting of text that prefix with numbers.

Output required:

- Evil Dead
- Fly machine
- Mario
- SimCity
- 4 cross Sudoku
- 15 cross Sudoku
- 20 cross Sudoku

Comment: ORDER BY columnName ASC http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_order_by.htm

Comment: I would do this in the java layer using Collections.sort() and a custom comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 ORDER BY CAST(column1 AS INTEGER), column1
```

Output:

```
|         column1 |
-------------------
|       Evil Dead |
|     Fly machine |
|           Mario |
|         SimCity |
|  4 cross Sudoku |
| 15 cross Sudoku |
| 20 cross Sudoku |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d621b/6)** demo

Comment: Will fail for `0` started strings.

Comment: @LS_dev Fair point, but that might not be a problem with real data

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM  [table] ORDER BY [column] GLOB '[0-9]*', [column];
```

will make the job.

```
SELECT * FROM [table] ORDER BY CAST([column] AS INTEGER), [column];
```

may be faster, but `0` started strings will appear before text.

EDIT:

Better option:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] ORDER BY TYPEOF([column])='text' DESC, [column];
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for sorting columns in SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT   [columns]
FROM     [table(s)]
WHERE    [conditions]
ORDER BY [columnName] ASC, [columnName] ASC, [columnName] ASC
```

You can order by as many columns as you wish (I have used three in this example) and you can replace the ASC with DESC to give ascending or desending sorting.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_order_by.htm

I would use the IFNULL statement on the first letter to test for a number first and include that as part of the sort order:

```
SELECT *
FROM testSort
ORDER BY IFNULL(substr(name,1) + 1, 0), name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/84fe6/9

Comment: How does it help to get OP's desired output?

Comment: @peterm Good point, didn't see the number bit, I've added an IFNULL to test for a number and sorted  by that

Answer (score 0):

if this has to be done within sql, you can use

```
select columnName from table ORDER BY round(columnName) ASC, columnName ASC
```